# Exported feature class attribute table fields containing data read as NULL or 0 length vectors in R

Tags: arcgis-desktop, shapefile, r, export, feature-class

I have encountered some odd behaviour trying to work with data exported from feature classes using the [Export Feature Attributes to ASCII tool](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/tools/spatial-statistics-toolbox/export-feature-attribute-to-ascii.htm) in ArcDesktop 10.4.1 (advanced licence).  The data looks like this with up to ~3000 rows:

[image]

I'm doing some further processing in R using the following for loop:

```
 for (row in 1:nrow(input_angles_t$`030918`)){
  S_tmpX <- input_angles_t$`030918`[row, "START_X"]
  S_tmpY <- input_angles_t$`030918`[row, "START_Y"]
  FID <- input_angles_t$`030918`[row, "FID"]
  for (row in 1:nrow(input_angles_t$`030918`)){
    if (input_angles_t$`030918`[row, "FID"] != FID & input_angles_t$`030918`[row, "START_X"] == S_tmpX & input_angles_t$`030918`[row, "START_Y"] == S_tmpY & input_angles_t$`030918`[row, "BEARING"] == 0){
      input_angles_t$`030918`[row, "BEARING"] <- 359
    }
  }
}
```

the `input_angles_t$`030918`` input is a data frame like that shown above.  When I run this loop on data exported from a shapefile, it works fine.  However, when I run the same loop on the same data but exported from a feature class in geodatabase, R throws the following error:

```
Error in if (input_angles_t$`030918`[row, "FID"] != FID & input_angles_t$`030918`[row,  :  argument is of length zero
```

I've looked into what this error means and it is to do with NULL or 0 length vector arguments that stop the if statement from evaluating.  I've checked for NULLs in the data and there aren't any.  What is weirder is that it runs the line `S_tmpX <- input_angles_t$`030918`[row, "START_X"]` and I get `S_tmpX` as an output before it throws an error saying that essentially the same line of code produces a zero length argument.  And as stated above, this ONLY happens on .csv exports from feature classes, not on exactly the same data from a shapefile.

Has anyone else ever come across similar problems and found a solution?  At the moment my solution will be to just work with shapefiles for this task, but I prefer file management with geodatabases, so if I could go back to using feature classes in GDBs, that would be preferable.

Comment: Is `input_angles_t$030918` a data.frame? Are you sure? Check if is a column of `input_angles_t`

Comment: No, it's a DF in a list of DFs (each is named by date, e.g 2003.09.18).  Each DF in the list has the columns in the example above.

Comment: Without reproducible data is difficult to identify the error